# Translate Joint constrained by custom axis

Tags: modeling, rigging

I'd like to translate a bones tail along an axis defined by itself and another joints head/tail, e.g:

[image: axis]

Is this possible? how do you do it?

Comment: You mean, in edit mode?  Snap cursor to head of one, set cursor as pivot point, select tail, scale to eye.  Can also be done with "active selection" pivot point-- fewer actions, but a little more difficult to describe.

Comment: Yea thats perfect thanks, I've only really played around a little with blender a bit so apologise for the bad question